# Modifying the foreign key of an existing model in the Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model which has a ForeignKey field, and I wish to change its value in a model instance, I tried something like this:

```
#object and user are model instances, owner is a FK field
object.owner = user
```

This raises a ValueError : "object.owner is not an instance of User"

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user should be a correct instance of User, and if you just created it instead of retrieved it from the database, it should be save()-d before you save object.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `user` is an instance of the same `User` that was used in defining the ForeignKey.